# Need help put new data in the table, using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm very very new to JS and client side, 
please help me to achieve this:

Every time I add subject to database, I want it to appear in the table.

html

```
    {% block main-menu %}
        <h3>Existing Subjects</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Documents</th>
                    <th>Followers</th>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>Updated</th>
                    <th>Posted By</th>
                </tr>
            <tbody>
            {% if subjects %}
                    <tr id="subject-description-main-menu-list">
                        <th id="subject-name"></th>
                        <th id="subject-docs"></th>
                        <th id="subject-followers"></th>
                        <th id="subject-created"></th>
                        <th id="subject-updated"></th>
                        <th id="subject-posted-by"></th>
                    </tr>
            {% endif %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {% endblock %}
```

And this is my Jquery:

```
function fill_subject_table_in_main_content() {
    $("#subject-description-main-menu-list").text('');
    $.get("/subject/list/", function(data){
        var FIELDS = ['name', 'num_of_followers', 'created_time', "created_by"];
        for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            for ( var j=0; j<FIELDS.length; j++) {
                $("#subject-description-main-menu-list").append('<th>'+data[i]['fields'][FIELDS[j]]+'</th>');
            }
        };
    }, 'json');
}
```

Data that I'm getting via get method is correct, but it appears in one row..... But I want it to be as a table...

now it looks like this:

```
Existing Subjects
Name    Documents   Followers   Created                           Updated   Posted By
Math 140       NONE             1         2012-08-17 08:04:02      NONE       r English 102 1   2012-08-17 08:04:14 r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're appending [header tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp) to the table. You'll want "td" instead. Second, you're calling .append on $("#subject-description-main-menu-list") which is a row. You should be appending rows to the table and appending the data to each row.

Something like:

```
for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
for ( var j=0; j<FIELDS.length; j++) {
    $(newRow).append('<td>'+data[i]['fields'][FIELDS[j]]+'</td>');
}
$("#yourTableId").append(newRow);
```

};